# reverse geocoding returns wrong address

Tags: android, ios, cllocationmanager, reverse-geocoding

I am getting latitude longitude and doing reverse geocoding in ios. This is what I have done so far.

```
-(void)GetLocationData
 {
if (self.locationManager == nil)
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
}
else
{
    nil;
}

if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
{
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
else
{
    nil;
}

self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;//kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
NSString *longitude;
NSString *latitude;

if (currentLocation != nil) {
    longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];//
    latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];//

    NSLog(@"Longitude-----%@-----Latitude----%@",longitude,latitude);
    dm.strLatitude=latitude;
    dm.strLongitude=longitude;
}

[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];



geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
// Reverse Geocoding
NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
CLLocationDegrees degreesLati=lati;
CLLocationDegrees degreesLongi=longi;
CLLocation *loc=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:degreesLati longitude:degreesLongi];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:loc completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
    if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
        placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:[placemarks count]-1];

        NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                             placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                             placemark.postalCode, placemark.subLocality,
                             placemark.subAdministrativeArea,
                            placemark.country];

       // NSString *address=[self.placemark];

        NSDictionary *dictAddress = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:placemark.addressDictionary];
        NSMutableDictionary *dictTxtData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        NSLog(@"country:%@",dictAddress);
        strCountry=placemark.country;

        NSLog(@"Address------%@",address);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
    }
} ];
```

}

But my problem is in Android and iOS returns 2 different addresses for this. But the Android Address is correct. This is how Android app get the address.

```
{
      Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);

      try {
           /**
           * Geocoder.getFromLocation - Returns an array of Addresses 
           * that are known to describe the area immediately   surrounding the given latitude and longitude.
           */
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, this.geocoderMaxResults);

           return addresses;
           } catch (IOException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
             Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
       }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Reverse Geocoding

```
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
    if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {

        placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:[placemarks count]-1];

        NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                             placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                             placemark.postalCode, placemark.subLocality,
                             placemark.subAdministrativeArea,
                            placemark.country];

       // NSString *address=[self.placemark];

        NSDictionary *dictAddress = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:placemark.addressDictionary];
        NSMutableDictionary *dictTxtData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];



        strCountry=placemark.country;

        NSLog(@"Address------%@",address);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
    }
} ];
```

This `currentLocation` I got in this way

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
  {
       CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
```

Answer (score 0):

**I wonna make a guess!!**

What are those `lati` and `longi`? Shouldn't you use `longitude` and `longitude` instead

```
CLLocationDegrees degreesLati = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
CLLocationDegrees degreesLongi = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
```

**Instead of:**

```
CLLocationDegrees degreesLati=lati;
CLLocationDegrees degreesLongi=longi;
```

Comment: I think hasan is on to something. You use variables `lati` and `longi` which are not defined anywhere in the code you posted. They must be instance variables from elsewhere. You also convert your latitude and longitude to strings. You should really save them as doubles and use the double values directly.

Comment: @DuncanC, exactly the string thing too. Didn't see that! If you don't wonna add an answer. please, allow me to add your point to mine.

Comment: By all means. You were "first out of the gate" with what appears to be the answer, so you should be the one.

Comment: sorry I actually hardcoded it just to check. that lati longi is  my current location lati longi

Comment: im assigning lati longi correctly. My problem is for same lati longi 2 apps returns 2 addresses

Comment: I am converting it to string just to send to the server. But for reverse geocodings I have used double values

Comment: Show where "lati" and "longi" are set then. It looks wrong to us, and you are getting wrong results. If you're convinced that some code is correct, but the results are wrong, it's time to revisit your assumptions.